# Why does function clearInterval() not working? I used setInterval too

Tags: javascript, timer, clearinterval

I'm creating a product hover effect where I used mouseover and mouseleave functions. However, I'm currently having problems with the clearInterval function on Javascript.
Do I miss on something? The structure is also aligned.
Here's my code:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ()=>{

    // //get img url from span
    // const src = spanElem.attr('data-original');

    // //change span to img using the value from data-original
    // spanElem.replaceWith('<img class="product-img-toadd w3-animate-fading" src="' + src + '"/>');


    const imgGallery = document.querySelectorAll('.product-img-gallery');
    
    const imageDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.product-tile__image');

    let interval

    imageDiv.forEach(el=>{
        //img
        const imgGalleryItem = el.querySelectorAll('.product-img-gallery__item')

        el.addEventListener("mouseenter", ()=>{
            imgGalleryItem.forEach(item=>{
                const src = item.getAttribute('data-original')
                const img = `<img class="product-img-toadd w3-animate-fading" src="${src}"/>`
                item.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',img)


                //slider
                const imgSlides = el.querySelectorAll('.product-img-toadd');
                let currentIndex = 0

                interval = setInterval(() => {
                    imgSlides.forEach((item) => {
                        item.style.opacity = 0;
                    });

                    imgSlides[currentIndex].style.opacity = 1;

                    if (currentIndex === imgSlides.length - 1) {
                        currentIndex = 0;
                    } else {
                        currentIndex = currentIndex + 1;
                    }
                    console.log("tick")
                }, 750);
            })
        })

        el.addEventListener("mouseleave", ()=>{
            const imgSlides = el.querySelectorAll('.product-img-toadd');
            imgSlides.forEach((item) => {
                item.style.opacity = 0;         
            });

            clearInterval(interval);
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: You assign to `interval` in a loop so any previous values are overwritten.  Perhaps call it once outside the loop and do all the work when it ticks.

Comment: Thank you @AlexK. but I'm curious how would I append my product gallery if I'll remove it from the loop? This is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You're assiging `interval` in a loop, overriding each previous element with the next.

A possible solution would be to push each interval to a array, then iterate through all elements and clear it's elements.

```
let intervals = [];
intervals.push( setInterval(() => { ... });
...

intervals.forEach((iv) => clearInterval(iv));
```